# hide/show options menu when clicking buttons

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I'm using some buttons in my fragments. When i checks those buttons then options menu should display. And when i uncheck it it should hide options menu. How should i do this

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mLocation = getArguments().getString(Beco.EXTRA_LOCATION);
    listMalls = temporaryModelCache.getDealData().getFacets().getArea();
    listCategories = temporaryModelCache.getDealData().getFacets().getCategories();
    listGender = temporaryModelCache.getDealData().getFacets().getAgeGroup();
    try {
        MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        if (activity != null) activity.hideBottomBar();
    } catch (Exception ignored) {

    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forgot_password, menu);
    mResetButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
        case  R.id.action_reset:
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick");
            resetFilter();
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And this is the event that i need to hide/display options menu

```
private void checkSelected() {
    if (!mapMall.isEmpty() || !mapGender.isEmpty() || !mapCategory.isEmpty()) {
        footerTab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else {
        footerTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

When `if (!mapMall.isEmpty() || !mapGender.isEmpty() || !mapCategory.isEmpty())` i need to display actions menu and in the `else` part i need to hide options menu ! How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call invalidateOptionsMenu() for hide and show option menu

```
 Boolean Isreset= false;

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.forgot_password, menu);
    mResetButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset);
    if(!Isreset)
    {
        mResetButton.setVisibility(true);
    }else{
        mResetButton.setVisibility(false);
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
        case  R.id.action_reset:
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick");
            resetFilter();
            Isreset= true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'setVisibility(boolean)' in             mResetButton.setVisibility(true);

Comment: i changed Boolean Isreset= false; to true and
menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset).setVisibility(true); and menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset).setVisibility(false);

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the instance of `Menu` object and later on use it to invalidate the options menu.

```
private Menu menu;


    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); 
        mLocation = getArguments().getString(Beco.EXTRA_LOCATION); 
        listMalls = temporaryModelCache.getDealData().getFacets().getArea(); 
        listCategories = temporaryModelCache.getDealData().getFacets().getCategories(); 
        listGender = temporaryModelCache.getDealData().getFacets().getAgeGroup(); 
        try { 
            MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
            if (activity != null) activity.hideBottomBar();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forgot_password, menu);
        mResetButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset);
        this.menu = menu;
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        switch (itemId) {
            case  R.id.action_reset:
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick");
                resetFilter(); 
                return true; 
        } 

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Using the `menu` object then toggle the options menu.

```
private void checkSelected() { 
    if (!mapMall.isEmpty() || !mapGender.isEmpty() || !mapCategory.isEmpty()) { 
        footerTab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    } else { 
        footerTab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_reset).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } 
}
```